# How can I change the placement of the caption and modify the color of cross-referencing in the R markdown generated pdf document?

Tags: r, pdf, latex, caption, cross-reference

````
---
title: "Annual Report"
author: "Xyz"
date: "`r format(Sys.time(),'%d %B, %Y')`"
output: 
  bookdown::pdf_document2:
    extra_dependencies: ["float"]
    number_sections: false
    toc: false

---


```{r, echo = FALSE}
library(ggplot2)
data(mtcars)
names(mtcars)
```
### Heading 1
```{r figure-1,echo=FALSE, fig.cap = "Sample Graph 1"}
ggplot(mtcars,aes(x=mpg,y=hp))+
  geom_point()+
  theme_classic()

```


To see another graph, please see figure \@ref(fig:figure-2)

\newpage
### Heading 2
```{r figure-2,echo=FALSE, fig.cap = "Sample Graph 2"}
ggplot(mtcars,aes(x=mpg,y=carb))+
  geom_point()+
  theme_classic()

```


To see another graph, please see figure \@ref(fig:figure-1)
````

I have tried to enclose @ref in the \textcolor{}{}, but Latex removes the cross-referencing and only shows **@ref(fig:figure-1)** in the knitted pdf document.

Moreover, I want to put the caption at the top of the figure instead of being at the bottom. I looked over Stackoverflow and users are recommending to use *floatrow* package to control the placement of caption, but I can't use *floatrow* with *float* package. I am using float package in my document to control for extra spaces in my document by using the following code written in Latex:

```
\usepackage{float}
\let\origfigure\figure
\let\endorigfigure\endfigure
\renewenvironment{figure}[1][2] {
    \expandafter\origfigure\expandafter[H]
} {
    \endorigfigure
}
```

Please help me out in sorting out these issues :)

Comment: Please don't ask multiple unrelated problems in a single post

Comment: It would have been better to answer the question along with your feedback @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz please explain how did my solution contradict my requirements stated in my own question.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure out the solution to both of the problems mentioned in my question. I am sharing my solution to both problems for the other learners below:

**Change the Cross-Reference Color**

We cannot use Latex *\textcolor{}{}* to change the color of the cross-referencing in R Markdown. My thinking is R Markdown confuses multiple Latex commands with simple words while knitting the document.

[Xie et al. (2020)](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/font-color.html) has addressed this problem by creating a lua filter. I opened "The Notepad" and copied the code given in the book. And I saved the file as **color-text.lua**. The code is given below for the reader's convenience:

```
Span = function(el)
  color = el.attributes['color']
  -- if no color attribute, return unchange
  if color == nil then return el end
  
  -- transform to <span style="color: red;"></span>
  if FORMAT:match 'html' then
    -- remove color attributes
    el.attributes['color'] = nil
    -- use style attribute instead
    el.attributes['style'] = 'color: ' .. color .. ';'
    -- return full span element
    return el
  elseif FORMAT:match 'latex' then
    -- remove color attributes
    el.attributes['color'] = nil
    -- encapsulate in latex code
    table.insert(
      el.content, 1,
      pandoc.RawInline('latex', '\\textcolor{'..color..'}{')
    )
    table.insert(
      el.content,
      pandoc.RawInline('latex', '}')
    )
    -- returns only span content
    return el.content
  else
    -- for other format return unchanged
    return el
  end
end
```

Once the file is saved, we need to incorporate *color-text.lua* in the YAML header of our required document. We will incorporate the lua file by modifying YAML header:

```
---
title: "Annual Report"
author: "Xyz"
date: "`r format(Sys.time(),'%d %B, %Y')`"
output: 
  bookdown::pdf_document2:
    pandoc_args: ["--lua-filter=color-text.lua"]
    number_sections: false
    toc: false

---
```

After modifying the YAML header, we can change the font color of cross-referenced text by doing it the following way:

```
To see another graph, please see figure [\@ref(fig:figure-2)]{color="blue"}
```

We need to write the cross-referenced text within square brackets followed by color argument within {}.

**Changing the placement of the caption and controlling for extra whitespaces**

If we want to change the placement of the caption and control for extra white space in our pdf document, we need to include the following lines in our .tex file

```
\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\floatsetup[figure]{capposition=top}
\floatplacement{figure}{H}
```

After saving the above tex file as caption_control.tex, we will include it in our YAML header:

```
---
title: "Annual Report"
author: "Xyz"
date: "`r format(Sys.time(),'%d %B, %Y')`"
output: 
  bookdown::pdf_document2:
    pandoc_args: ["--lua-filter=color-text.lua"]
    number_sections: false
    toc: false
    includes:
       in_header: caption.control.tex

---
```